# g++ 4.7 strict-aliasing check invalid

Tags: c++, g++

When I compile the following code with `g++ 4.7`.

```
g++ -Wall -fstrict-aliasing
```

I will get warning on the first cast:

`warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]`

The second cast is fine without any warning. Can any one help me understand why warning on the first cast ?

```
int main()
{
    char a [16];
    char * p = &a[0];

    //int i = *((int *)(&a[0])); //bad
    int j = *((int *)(p));  //ok
    return  0;
}
```

Comment: This article may help you: http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html

Comment: The second one is not ok, the compiler just doesn't tell you. Possibly because it isn't *absolutely* certain that you haven't assigned an `int*` to `p` earlier.

Comment: Wow, just verified that here.  Pretty disappointing since, in my own experience, this is the most common way I employ aliased pointers in my own code.  Eg. I'll cast to char to allow for easy arithmetic and then cast to the underlying stream type to pull in data.  Note that such use cases of aliasing are fine so long as you're only reading data.  The optimizer is only at risk for generating broken code when reading/writing the same memory from different pointers (which btw is a bad idea on newer x86 architectures anyway because it can invoke store-forwarding hazards at the cpu/cache level).

Comment: Keep in mind that the GCC docs have this to say about `-Wstrict-aliasing`: This option is only active when -fstrict-aliasing is active. It warns about code that might break the strict aliasing rules that the compiler is using for optimization. **The warning does not catch all cases**, but does attempt to catch the more common pitfalls.

Answer (score 4):

> The second cast is fine without any warning. Can any one help me understand why warning on the first cast ?

That's not the question you should be asking. The question you should be asking is why the second cast doesn't display a warning, even though it's exactly as problematic as the first cast.

No warning is issued for `(int *) p`, because `p` *could*, based on its type, have been legitimately obtained by casting a pointer-to-int to `char *`. However, unless that is the case, dereferencing the result is still not allowed. Even if you don't get a warning.

Note that the warning is independent of the optimisations that could "break" your code. Your code could get a warning and work as intended. Your code could not get a warning and fail.